# SoundCloud: Updating Track Metadata not working

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I am using version 3.0.0 of the JavaScript SDK. I manage to connect, get tracks and upload new tracks. However, updating track metadata is not working. For example:

```
SC.put('/tracks/231833159', {
    track: {
        title: "New Track Title"
    }
});
```

Response to the OPTIONS request:

```
Request URL: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/231833159?
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
```

It seems like the `SC.put` call omits the parameters for format and the oauth token.

Is it a bug in the new SC API v3.0.0 or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug which was fixed in SDK version 3.1.0.

https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/commit/a98734b43c827c445baa4f7d86e2b84204c3dfec

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround**

You can manually add the oauth_token to the URL. The hacky, the '&' at the end of the URL, is necessary because the API wrapper appends a '?'.

```
SC.put('/tracks/' + track.id + '?format=json&oauth_token=' + oauth_token + '&', {
    track: {
        title: "New Track Title"
    }
});
```